# Wilcoxon Signed-Rank Test N>300

Tags: wilcoxon-signed-rank, research-design

There were similar questions here but as a person with little knowledge about statistics I couldn't understand any of it. I was looking for critical value tables that reached up to to higher amounts or if there was any formula so that I could calculate for it but I couldn't find any definite answer.

Is there a formula that I could use to calculate for critical values with N that reaches up to over 300?

Comment: with that sample size it's very likely that the normal approximation is fine.

Comment: Also, whatever software you're using to calculate the signed-rank test statistic should output p values as well as the signed rank test statistic. (I'm assuming you're not calculating the signed-rank test statistic by hand)

Comment: 1. The normal approximation is very suitable for normal use at considerably smaller sample sizes than 300. 2. Statistics programs can do exact p-values out a lot further than it would be practical to carry tables for (R, for example, seems to work into the thousands).